# Tensorflow.js print() and dataSync methods on model.predict not working

Tags: tensorflow.js

I've distilled this down to as few lines of code as I could to get to the bottom of this issue.

currently these are the config constants below (I'm using a array of length 1 to represent tokenised words I'm doing semantic analysis on.

```
export const top_words = 10000; 
export const max_review_length = 1
export const embedding_vector_length = 32
```

Here is the code, I've substituted the tensors with mock tokens or one word length for now. I'm getting typescript linting errors showing that .print() or .dataSync()[0] will fail on the basis that they do not exist. the line of code in question (.predict) is returning a tensor which has no print or datasync method

```
const x_train = tf.tensor([[80], [86], [10], [1], [2]]);
const y_train = tf.tensor([[1],[1],[1],[0],[0]])
const x_val = tf.tensor([[1], [3], [102], [100], [104]]);
const y_val = tf.tensor([[0],[0],[1],[1],[1]])
const model = tf.sequential();


model.add(tf.layers.embedding({ inputDim: dictionary.size, inputLength: max_review_length, outputDim: 1 }))
model.add(tf.layers.lstm({units: 200, dropout: 0.2, recurrentDropout: 0.2}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation:'sigmoid'}))
model.compile({ loss:'binaryCrossentropy', optimizer:'rmsprop', metrics:['accuracy'] }) 
const history=model.fit(x_train, y_train,{epochs: 12, batchSize: 5}) 
history.then(hist => console.log(hist.history.loss)) // Show error loss vs epoch

const predictOut =  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([10]))
```

predictOut.print() or predictOut.dataSync()[0]
returns

Comment: Are they just linting errors or does the code really throw an exception?

Comment: Property 'dataSync' does not exist on type 'Tensor<Rank> | Tensor<Rank>[]'. or proptery 'print' ...

Comment: Is that a runtime exception or a linting error?

Comment: Its both linting and runtime

Comment: What logs when you try `console.log(predictOut)`?

Comment: i get a tensor (this is the log).. {
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 1, 1 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  size: 1,
  strides: [ 1 ],
  dataId: {},
  id: 82295,
  rankType: '2' }

Answer (score 7):

If you are using TypeScript you need to specify what predict() returns in such way:

```
(model.predict(...) as tf.Tensor).print()
```

since predict() can return either a Tensor or Tensor[]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so one thing thats easy to forget if you're not used to dealing with Python. Python is syncronous!

the model is async so to solve this problem in this code.
history (the result)

```
history.then(result => {
  model.predict(tftensor2d([10)).print()
  console.log('loss ', result.history.loss)
}
```

otherwise the model doesnt yet have a predict method as it is still calculating.

Gotta love async.